# Read-only DB user can run SQL queries?

Tags: mysql

If I create a read-only user, does it give them the ability to run SQL queries? We have setup a read-only user, and when they connected to the database they were not able to perform `SELECT` queries...

`ERROR: (conn=*****) SELECT command denied to user`

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by "read-only" user? what does `show grants` show for this user?

Comment: Have you committed the grant? Are you really connecting to the *same* database? Check everything; it’s easy to get wires crossed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hope you executed FLUSH PRIVILEGES; after GRANT statement.
2. Did you try connecting with the same username and password to make sure it works for you ?